# Angularjs data-ng-controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a simple inline controller which isn't working. I am unable to find the bug. I have tested this with ng-init and printed out with ng-repeat, works fine. With ng-controller, it doesn't.

```
<html data-ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
Name: 
<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name}} ---- {{cust.city}}</li>
</ul>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
function SimpleController($scope){
    $scope.customers=[{name:'John Doe', city:'New York'},{name:'Jane Doe', city:'Melbourne'},{name:'Jack Daniels',city:'Atlanta'}];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: angular version should be less tha 1.2 for global controllers :-)

Comment: Oh...no I am using 1.3.x stable. Any alternative to make this code work with 1.3?

Comment: Yes you have to define your app name and register it using `myApp.controller("SimpleController", SimpleController)` after you've defined that function.

Comment: @OmriAharon: you need to define myApp to specify the controller method for it.

Comment: Yes use module to use it.

Comment: @V31 In this case, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the app initiated in javascript using

```
angular.module
```

for the app name you specifying in data-ng-app

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/focykzmf/)

Javascript Code:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
        name: 'John Doe',
        city: 'New York'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        city: 'Melbourne'
    }, {
        name: 'Jack Daniels',
        city: 'Atlanta'
    }];
});
```

Comment: it is when specifying it in html as angular will try to find the app in script and will error out.

Comment: coz you not specified the app name, however the OP has mentioned the app name in ng-app

Comment: `<html data-ng-app>` There is no app name specified.

Comment: aah the OP was using 1.2 the answer is for 1.3 gud observation @OmriAharon

Answer (score 1):

Lots of chatter in the comments so I'll sum this in an answer.

As @squiroid correctly stated, the use of global controllers (meaning define a function and then just reference it) has been removed in recent Angular versions and in 1.3 specifically.

You have to define your module and register your controller to it, so in overall you need:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

function SimpleController($scope){
    $scope.customers=[{name:'John Doe', city:'New York'},{name:'Jane Doe', city:'Melbourne'},{name:'Jack Daniels',city:'Atlanta'}];
}

myApp.controller("SimpleController", SimpleController); //This is a must now
```

And in your view you need to refer to your module:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine in angular 1.2 version.

but in case if you are using angular 1.3+ it will not.

With angular 1.3 you can no longer use global controller declaration on the global scope. You would need to define the controller using inline declaration.

In your HTML:

```
<html data-ng-app="app">
```

In js:

```
    angular.module('app', []).controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
        $scope.customers=[{name:'John Doe', city:'New York'},{name:'Jane Doe', city:'Melbourne'},{name:'Jack Daniels',city:'Atlanta'}];
    });
```

or with your existing controller:

```
     angular.module('app', []).controller('SimpleController', SimpleController)
```

Answer (score 0):

V31,

You definitely need to bootstrap your module since you are using 1.3 because using controller as a global function like you've done has been deprecated in 1.3.

See a complete working example below.  Try it out and see if it helps you.

```
<html data-ng-app="customersApp">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
Name:
<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name}} ---- {{cust.city}}</li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('customersApp', [])
    app.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
    { name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York' },
    { name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'Melbourne' },
    { name: 'Jack Daniels', city: 'Atlanta' }
        ];
    }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

SO1

Answer (score 0):

For best practice in angular use module  (I am not considering Angular 2.0 where module is dead):-

And for controllers use "controller as " and bind data on controller not on $scope.

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="SimpleController as ctrl">Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.name">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in ctrl.customers | filter:ctrl.name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name}} ---- {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Ctrl:-

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller('SimpleController', function () {
    this.customers = [{
        name: 'John Doe',
        city: 'New York'
    }, {
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        city: 'Melbourne'
    }, {
        name: 'Jack Daniels',
        city: 'Atlanta'
    }];
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpyrqk37/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I did 2 examples using Angular 1.2.26 and 1.3.12

Example using 1.3.12

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <!--<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body  ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name: 
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name}} ---- {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('test', []);

        app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
             $scope.customers=[{name:'John Doe', city:'New York'},
                              {name:'Jane Doe', city:'Melbourne'},
                              {name:'Jack Daniels',city:'Atlanta'}];
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The main changes here were the use of **module** and **controller** inside script

Example using version 1.2.26

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    Name: 
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{cust.name}} ---- {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        function SimpleController($scope){
            $scope.customers=[{name:'John Doe', city:'New York'},
                              {name:'Jane Doe', city:'Melbourne'},
                              {name:'Jack Daniels',city:'Atlanta'}];
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here the only change I did was add **ng-app=""** in body